'Could not chdir to home directory /home/me: No such file or directory' after updating Ubuntu Server
We recently had a power outage and I had to restart my Ubuntu machine. For some reason the resolution was messed up and I could not change it (the monitor was unrecognized). I updated Ubuntu, but this did not fix the issue. Now, when I ssh into the computer remotely I get a different interface without the standard directories (e.g. Desktop, Documents etc). I also receive the following message
Could not chdir to home directory /home/me: No such file or directory
To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.

I'm not sure what happened to my computer, and any advice is welcome.

Do you see any directories in /home (e.g. with ls -A /home)?

I tried creating a directory called /home/me, and now the warning message disappears when I ssh in. If I ls in that home directory there is nothing. If I try ls -A /home I see my name and user, but they are not directories. Really weird. I have no clue what is going on.

Can you [edit] your question to show exactly the output of ls -A? Did you perhaps have an encrypted home directory that has somehow stopped being decrypted + mounted? As well, please include your Ubuntu version information - what did you update from and to?

The output of ls -A in my home directory shows nothing.

Sorry I meant /home, not your (newly created) /home/me - I'm trying to understand what "I see my name and user, but they are not directories" means exactly

The output of ls -A in my home directory shows nothing. If I try ls -A /home it shows chrisblair user, neither or which are directories. When I log on it says Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 6.5.0-1021-oracle x86_64)

Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
Support:        https://ubuntu.com/pro

